# VB LAN Messenger having issues

Tags: vb.net, tcp, messenger, instant

I have made a small LAN messenger and I tried it with two pc's and it didnt work however running two of the applications with one listening to port 40004 and writing to 40005 and one listening to 40005 and writing to 40004 works. 
The problem seems to be in the sendb_click where I send the message. It says Receipent not connected.
Error message:

```
System.net.sockets.socketexception (0x80004005); No connection could be made 
because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:40003 
at system.net.sockets.tcpclient..ctor(string hostname,int32 port)
at messenger.form2.sendb_click(object sender, eventargs e) in 
D:\Messenger\Messenger\Form2.vb:line 97
```

:[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaj5V.png)
When connected you can choose a computer that is connected to the network on the right and message it. Im planning on having generated ports or whatever but for testing ive just made 40004 and 40005 the ports.

What is going wrong? Do i have to port forward or something?

below is my code

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Dns
Imports System.DirectoryServices

Public Class Form2
Class entity
    Public name As String
    Public ip As String
    Public port As Integer
End Class

Public reciepent As New entity
Public user As New entity
Public CLient As New TcpClient
Public listener As New TcpListener(40003)

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    usernametb.Text = user.name
    FindingThreats()
    getmyip()
    ipl.Text = user.ip
    user.port = 40003
    portl.Text = user.port
    ' listener = New TcpListener(40004)
    Dim ListThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
    ListThread.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub Listening()
    listener.Start()
End Sub

Sub FindingThreats()
    UsersL.Items.Clear()
    Dim childEntry As DirectoryEntry
    Dim ParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry
    Try
        ParentEntry.Path = "WinNT:"
        For Each childEntry In ParentEntry.Children
            Select Case childEntry.SchemaClassName
                Case "Domain"

                    Dim SubChildEntry As DirectoryEntry
                    Dim SubParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry
                    SubParentEntry.Path = "WinNT://" & childEntry.Name
                    For Each SubChildEntry In SubParentEntry.Children
                        Select Case SubChildEntry.SchemaClassName
                            Case "Computer"
                                UsersL.Items.Add(SubChildEntry.Name)
                        End Select
                    Next
            End Select
        Next
    Catch Excep As Exception
        MsgBox("Error While Reading Directories : " + Excep.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        ParentEntry = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub

Sub getmyip()
    For Each ip As Net.IPAddress In
        GetHostEntry(GetHostName).AddressList
        user.ip = ip.ToString
    Next
End Sub

Sub getip(strhostname As String, returnip As String)
    Try
        returnip = GetHostByName(strhostname).AddressList(0).ToString()
        reciepent.ip = returnip
    Catch
        MsgBox("This user is Offline.")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UsersL.SelectedIndexChanged
    CUL.Items.Clear()
    CUL.Items.Add("Connected Users:")
    Dim ip As String
    Dim hostname = UsersL.SelectedItem.ToString
    getip(hostname, ip)
    reciepent.port = 40004
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    CUL.Items.Add(user.name)
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub SendB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SendB.Click
    Try
        CLient = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 40004) 'reciepent.port)
        Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(CLient.GetStream())
        Writer.Write(ChatB.Text)
        ChatL.Items.Add("> " & ChatB.Text)
        Writer.Flush()
    Catch
        MsgBox("Receipent not connected.")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim message As String
    If listener.Pending = True Then
        message = ""
        CLient = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(CLient.GetStream())
        While Reader.Peek > -1
            message = message + Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
        End While
        ChatL.Items.Add("< " & message)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FindingThreats()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    listener.Stop()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: at first glance in your code you have the listener set at port 40003 and trying to connect a tcp client to port 40004 which the machine will actively refused it

Comment: Yes but the other computer will have the code listen at 40004 and connect to 40003

Comment: there's no need to change the port since you are using a TCP connection. This would be valid if using UDP

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using UDP for this? From what I understand both computer are running the same app? You would use a TCP connection if you were to have a server app that keeps track of status and use UDP to send your messages or use the server app to route the messages to the right user. BUT if your app is only for peer-to-peer messaging than switch your code to use UDP connection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx